# jqModal popup does not opens

Tags: drupal-6, jqmodal

I'm using drupal 6 form, and ahah for ajax form submit. On form submit I perform some validation and allows user to choose options that display on jqModal popup.
JS script that I'm using for jqm popup is:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#dialog").jqm();

        });
```

and uses  tag to open the jqm popup

```
        <a href="#" class="jqModal">Choose option</a>
        <div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog">

            <h2 id="modalHeading">Select one</h2>
            <a href="#" class="button-x jqmClose">x</a>
            <form> form values</form>
         </div>
```

Instead of opening popup window, it changes the url by adding # at the end.
Same code is working fine on the other page of my website.
jqModal.js file is included to the page on pageload.

Answer (score 0):

The default trigger is any element with a class of "jqModal", so your anchor element (Choose option) is correct and ought to show the modal when clicked.

Is anything showing up in the javascript console of the page?

Perhaps there's another javascript function that's preventing the click event from bubbling? The .click() events are assigned in a FILO (first-in, last-out) manner, so if another click event return false, the jqModal assigned event may never get called.

You can also be explicit and try;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").jqm({trigger: false});

  $("a.jqModal").click(function(){
    $("#dialog").jqmShow();
  });
});
```